# multiple classes in a single file : modifier private not allowed here

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I am not able to understand why this code doesn't compile:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

private class B {
    int a;
}
```

I am saving the contents in a file named `A.java` - and I get an error:

```
modifier private not allowed here // where I have defined class B
```

This happens both when I try B as private and protected. Can someone please explain me the reason behind this?

Thanks !

Comment: Inner classes can be private.

Comment: No, it does not seem to depend on A

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the [Java Language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1):

> The access modifiers protected and private pertain only to member classes within a directly enclosing class declaration

So yes, the private and the protected modifiers are not allowed for top level class declarations.

**Top-level** classes may be public or not, while `private` and `protected` are not allowed. If the class is declared public, then it can be referred to from any package. Otherwise it can only be referred to from the same package (namespace).

A private top level class wouldn't make much sense because it couldn't be referred to from any class. It would be unusable by definition. `private` is OK for member classes to make a class referable to only it's enclosing class.

A protected member class can be referred to from (1) any class of the same package and from (2) any subclass of the enclosing class. Mapping this concept to top level classes is difficult. The first case is covered by top level class with no access modifiers. The second case is not applicable for top level classes, because there is no enclosing class or something else from a different package with a special relation to this class (like a subclass). Because of this I think, `protected` is not allowed because it's underlying concept is not applicable for top level classes.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but can you please make me understand why might the Java developers would have imposed this restriction ? I know this question may sound absurd, but I am curious. Thanks !

Comment: OK. Got the logic for private, but what about protected ?? 'Protected' is certainly more open than the 'default' specifier - which has been allowed !

Answer (score 4):

Make the B nested of A, like this:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    private class B {
        int a;
    }
}
```

Or move B to a separate file. Also you can stick with default access level,
this way the class can be accessed only from  within the package:

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    } 
}

class B {
    int a;
}
```

Comment: I dont want to nest, or move to different file. I just want to know the cause of error

Comment: The error is actually obvious. If you don't do it nested or separate file the class will not be accessible from anywhere, since it is private. You cannot make it public also, cause java has a restriction of one public top-level class per file.

Comment: Protected makes no sense for top level classes. Since if it has default access level (no modifier specified) it is accessible from withing the package, if public -- it is also accessible from outside the package. Protected doesn't adds anything to this. Btw I forgot to notice that you may use default access level. See the answer update.

Answer (score 1):

*private and protected are meaningless to be allowed to a top level(not member) class/interface.*

They are applicable only to the class members which can be variables, constants, constructors, methods, classes, and interfaces.

**Why:**

(1) **private:** What may be the meaning/purpose if we define a class as private. Its scope should be private to some area. default access is already package private. And nobody wants a class to be source file private, (Guessing the reason) it may not be a good programming practice to allow because java applications are finally organized in the form of packages, but not in terms of source files. Any source file should be part of some package, so in broad/final view each class/interface is part of some package, not just of some .java file. So not applicable.

(2) **protected**: If something is protected it should be available only within package and only to the sub classes in other packages. To extend a class in a different package, it should be available to all the classes in other packages, but protected says class should be available only to the classes extended it. It's a kind of deadlock situation. So not applicable.

Source: My readings and understanding

Comment: As long as it is not public a class can have a name different from its file name. The class can also have main method. Class file will be generated with the class name but not with the source file name. The class name should be used to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Just have no private/protected modifier at all.

Comment: I meant to say I have tried both private and protected separately, but it doesnt work in both cases

Comment: I am just experimenting with access control, I just want to know the reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

B needs to be private to something.  Place it within the definition of class A or create another file, B.java, and define it there, but then it cannot be private.

Comment: Is that a rule in Java to make a class/ variable private or protected "to something" ? Cant we have standalone classes/ variables private or protected ?

Comment: My statement was more abstract than conceptual.  The fundamental issue was that you were declaring another class in the A.java file.  It appeared that you wanted to make B private to A or within 'something'.  However your statement regarding can we have stand alone classes private or protected doesn't really make sense because the modifiers only have context when they are relative to something.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't use the public keyword for the class it will be private by default (visible only within the file).

There can be only one public class per .java file, all the others need to be private. So class A can be public and class B doesn't need any modifiers in your example. The public class name must match the .java file name (eg. A.java can only contain one public class called "A").

Comment: This is not correct. A top level class with no modifier is *package* private. It can be referred to from any class within the same package.

Answer (score -2):

`A.java` cannot contain two classes.

Comment: Yes it can, as long as only one is public (the one that gives the source file its name) and all other non-public (no access modifier, a.k.a package accessible), a source file can contain multiple classes.