# Android glide: crop - cut off X pixels from image bottom

Tags: android, crop, android-glide

I need to cut off 20px from the image bottom and cache it so the device doesn't have to crop it over and over again every time the user sees the image again, otherwise it would be bad for battery etc. right?

This is what I have so far:

```
        Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(imgUrl)
            .into(holder.image)



fun cropOffLogo(originalBitmap: Bitmap) : Bitmap {

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
        originalBitmap,
        0,
        0,
        originalBitmap.width,
        originalBitmap.height - 20
    )
}
```

how could I use `cropOffLogo` with `glide`?

EDIT:

I tried using https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations#custom-transformations

```
private static class CutOffLogo extends BitmapTransformation {

    public CutOffLogo(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform,
                               int outWidth, int outHeight) {

        Bitmap myTransformedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                toTransform,
                10,
                10,
                toTransform.getWidth(),
                toTransform.getHeight() - 20);

        return myTransformedBitmap;
    }
}
```

And get those errors:

```
Modifier 'private' not allowed here

Modifier 'static' not allowed here

'BitmapTransformation()' in 'com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'
```

Comment: Probably you are creating the class in the wrong place. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491131/multiple-classes-in-a-single-file-modifier-private-not-allowed-here)

Comment: I made it in the same place where other classes are. I don't get any errors when changing private static to public abstract but still have the "'BitmapTransformation()' in 'com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)" error on context in super(context);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Transformation

To cut some pixels from the image you can create new (custom) transformation. In Kotlin:

```
class CutOffLogo : BitmapTransformation() {
    override fun transform(
        pool: BitmapPool,
        toTransform: Bitmap,
        outWidth: Int,
        outHeight: Int
    ): Bitmap =
        Bitmap.createBitmap(
            toTransform,
            0,
            0,
            toTransform.width,
            toTransform.height - 20   // numer of pixels
        )

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {}
}
```

or in Java:

```
public class CutOffLogo extends BitmapTransformation {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap transform(
            @NotNull BitmapPool pool,
            @NotNull Bitmap toTransform,
            int outWidth,
            int outHeight
    ) {

        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                toTransform,
                0,
                0,
                toTransform.getWidth(),
                toTransform.getHeight() - 20   // numer of pixels
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDiskCacheKey(@NonNull MessageDigest messageDigest) {

    }
}
```

## Call it

In Kotlin

```
.transform(CutOffLogo())
```

or in Java

```
.transform(new CutOffLogo())
```

Answer (score 0):

See about [Transformations on Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations) and do your [custom Transformation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Transformations#custom-transformations).

Comment: I get all kind of errors with this class: Modifier 'private' not allowed here, Modifier 'static' not allowed here, 'BitmapTransformation()' in 'com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation' cannot be applied to '(android.content.Context)'

Comment: Can you add this attempt to the question?

Comment: Ok I did, I didn't really learn JAVA so far, it's absolutely disgusting compared to Kotlin xD